# What is the general solution to Laplace's equation in 3d?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, laplacian

I've searched online but most make assumptions such as the solution can be separated into a product of functions which are each only depend on say x, y, or z. Or they assume the solution is only a function of the radius. What is the general solution? Are there multiple general solutions or is there only one unique general solution?

Comment: PDE’s typically don’t have truly general solutions without initial or boundary conditions.

Comment: There is no unique solution, so a general solution is out of the question.

Comment: It depends on your boundary conditions